# How to query Log Analytics data into Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer

I need to query my Log Analytics workspace into Azure Data Explorer but i didn't fined any idea about it.

Below are my doubts?
1. Do i need to ingest data from Log Analytics to Azure Data Explorer before utilizing it?
2. I didn't find any way to make a connection to Log Analytics into Azure Data Explorer?
3. The only option i saw to ingest data in Azure Data Explorer is through Event Hub. But now my issue is how can i ingest my log analytics data into Azure Data Explorer using event hub? Do i need to write any process to ingest?

If anyone have then please share so that I can explore about it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Log Analytics team is working on a direct solution to ingest data to Azure Data 
Explorer, meanwhile please export Log Analytics data and ingest data into ADX using the ingest API's or Logic Apps ([Event Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub)) to setup the export of Log Analytics data to Event Hub.

Comment: How is the state of affairs as of today? Still no streamlined solution?